# How to include imported modules in an export?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, ecmascript-6, vue.js

This is the module I'm exporting. Nothing much, just initializing [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)'s JavaScript SDK:

**mixin.js:**

```
import Parse from 'parse'

var ParseMixin = {
  created: function () {
    Parse.initialize('APP_ID', 'CLIENT_ID')
  }
}

export default ParseMixin
```

And this is how I'm importing it and using it:

**main.js:**

```
import ParseMixin from '../mixins'

export default {
  mixins: [ParseMixin],

  methods: {
    submit () {
      const project = {
        title: this.title,
        content: this.content
      }

      const Obj = Parse.Object.extend(store.class)
      const obj = new Obj()
      obj.save(project).then(() =>
        console.log('Saved.')
      )

      ...
```

However, right now I get this error:

> error  no-undef  "Parse" is not defined
>   /home/alex/node/cotrib/src/components/ProjectList.js:54:19
>           const Obj = Parse.Object.extend(store.class)

Because `Parse` is not being imported from `mixin.js`.

How to modify the code so that `Parse` is also imported?

Comment: Why not just `import Parse from 'Parse'` in the other file as well? That's typically better than aliasing modules on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to reference `Parse` in `main.js`, then you should load it there:

```
// main.js
import Parse from 'parse'
import ParseMixin from '../mixins'
```

Every module should import its dependencies.

---

You could expose `Parse` from `ParseMixin` if you wanted to:

```
// mixins.js
export {Parse};

// main.js
import ParseMixin, {Parse} from '../mixins';
```

but having default and named exported seems to be more confusing than directly importing the dependency.